# What is the recommended ID to use for banning users in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an app that provides a special content to users that users have to get points to use. However this content isn't supposed to be shared with others. However some users decide they want to share it regardless of that. Those who do this are banned from app. In google play when I upload an app to beta release in security prelaunch report I see I get that I'm using device identifiers(Android ID in my case) with all the warning following

I've gone through what google recommends here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html
However these recommendation never fit my goal which is to prevent those users violating my rules from using my app

Each user have a unique tag for each install instance. But this isn't related to the device id. It is a random generated ID on server. Thus this can't be used to identify users. I'm not aiming to use this data in Advertising activities as I want users to stay anonymous out of my app. But on the other hand I don't want to lose the value of my content

Android ID seems the only way to do it from what I know & seen so far. Is there another way that will prevent that warning from showing in google play & at the same time be able to prevent those users from using my app when they violate my rules?

Comment: Surely these users have accounts with your system they are earning points against?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that I each user have a unique tag for each install instance. But this isn't related to the device id. It is a random generated ID on server(added to question)